Error "Failed building wheel for numpy" mlagents Unity
I am learning about Ml agents in Unity so I was trying to follow the Documentation Installation for Unity Ml-agents, but when I tried to install the mlagents Python package, I got this error:
TypeError: CCompiler_spawn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'env'
[end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Successfully built mlagents_envs
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I installed all the recommended versions of python (3.10.12) and Unity editor (2023.2+) and the project is in an anaconda environment so I don't find any "pyproject.toml" as in a similar post, so I don't know what can be the problem. How can I fix it?
